# Permutation - fruit problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I need help on how to do a task.
How many packages can we make? The packages have $7$ fruits.

We have $6$ peaches, $3$ bananas, $3$ oranges, $3$ apples, and $1$ lemon.

Let's assume that we do not differentiate between the same fruit.

Comment: You can make write a program to solve it, I got $113$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the coefficient of $x^7$ in

$$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)(1+x+x^2+x^3)^3(1+x)$$

Multiplying the polynomial out:

[Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E5%2Bx%5E6%29%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%29%5E3%281%2Bx%29)

gives

$$x^{16} + 5 x^{15} + 14 x^{14} + 30 x^{13} + 52 x^{12} + 76 x^{11} + 98 x^{10} + 113 x^9 + 118 x^8 + 113 x^7 + 98 x^6 + 76 x^5 + 52 x^4 + 30 x^3 + 14 x^2 + 5 x + 1$$

which gives the answers for any number of fruit, in particular $113$ possible assortments for $7$ fruits.

Comment: But how does it help solve the problem?

Comment: @youthdoo; just multiply the polynomial out,

Comment: @yourthdoo this technique makes use of generating functions. Have you seen this before?